# Rigged model seperates torso from the legs when moving the bones

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

So when I try moving the legs for example, this happens: [image]

I understand this is because the model is seperated into different objects. But is there any way to make them share the weight without joining the objects together?

Comment: you need to give it some corrections in Weight Paint mode, maybe create an additional bone?

Comment: It looks like legs are a separate mesh. The whole modelshould be one piece.

Comment: The model doesn't need to be one object if the weights match. You can go into edit mode and copy the weight vertex per vertex. If the geometry overlaps you can isolate that edge loop and try the data transfer modifier. If this was a shared edge loop you can duplicate the loop from one mesh, separate it and merge it into the other mesh in which you delete the overlapping loop and reconnect the merged loopö.

Comment: Ditto, I just made a character that had about 10 pieces and automatic weight paint works just fine most of the time (especially for characters that otherwise WOULD have all their parts welded together, like pants and torsos).

If the separated meshes are separate objects, de-parent them and re-parent with automatic weights. If your rig is fine, this will work.

If the seperated meshes are ONE object, select all faces in one mesh, CTRL-P to make its own object, then do same for other. De-parent each from the armature. Re-parent with automatic weights.